# Specialize template for const T& for big types and T for simple types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I need to do this magic:

I have a template:

```
template <class T>
void Foo(const T& value)
```

But I need to specialize it for simple types, for example, `bool`, `int`, etc so it will be passed by const value, not by const reference:

```
template <>
void Foo<bool>(const bool value)

template <>
void Foo<int>(const int value)

// and so on, including std::nullptr_t

template <>
void Foo<std::nullptr_t>(std::nullptr_t)
{
   // some special behavior
}
```

But it cannot be compiled.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Can you use Boost? It has [`boost::call_traits<T>::param_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) which does exactly this.

Comment: Couldn't you just overload rather than specialize ?

Comment: @TartanLlama call traits are not deducible

Comment: Please note that the compiler is able to perform this transformation as an optimization itself. So you might not have to do this (depending on the context) if you need this only as an optimization. Example: https://godbolt.org/g/mJHdY0 Here, gcc changes the function signature from `void(int const&, char*)`  to `void(int, char*)`.

Answer (score 5):

If the functionality for all fundamental types and pointers is the same I guess you can make use of [std::is_fundamental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental), [std::is_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) and [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value>
foo(const T) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<T>::value>
foo(const T&) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Example on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XJDyn2ioUSunX5Dz)

Comment: Note: With the exception of `std::nullptr_t`, this solution takes pointer types by [`const T&`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/no8R5k66sIQ5SwYN) rather than by value.

Comment: @WhiZTiM and also for all pointer types, I've added `std::is_pointer`. Also I've added `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)` for small structs.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Thank you for pointing me out, I completely missed the case of pointers!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use tagged dispatch and perfect forwarding....

```
template<typename T>
void Foo_dispatch(T val, std::true_type){
    std::cout << val << " Passed by value\n";
}

template<typename T>
void Foo_dispatch(const T& val, std::false_type){
    std::cout << val << " Passed by reference\n";
}

void Foo(std::nullptr_t){}

template <class T>
void Foo(T&& value){
    using type = std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_fundamental<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value>;
    Foo_dispatch(std::forward<T>(value), type());
}
```

Example Usage:

```
int main(){
    Foo(23);
    Foo(45.343);
    Foo("Hahah");
    Foo(std::string("Cool stuff"));
    Foo(nullptr);
    Foo(&"huhu");
}
```

Produces:

```
23 Passed by value
45.343 Passed by value
Hahah Passed by reference
Cool stuff Passed by reference
nullptr_t gotten
0x400e52 Passed by value
```

See it [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba03d0e2b5f60221)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's because

```
void Foo<bool>(const bool value)
```

is not *specialization* of

```
template <class T>
void Foo(const T& value)
```

but it is its *overload* (with functions it is different from class templates, because functions can overload).

What you can do is for example:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    void operator ()(const T& value);
};

template <>
struct Foo<bool> {
    void operator ()(bool value);
};

// ... other specializations
```

(or just use simple non-templated overloads, as they take precedence over template instantiation)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
template <class T>
void Foo(const T& value)
{
 return ; 
}

void Foo(const bool value)
{ }

void Foo(const int value)
{ }
// and so on, including std::nullptr_t


void Foo(std::nullptr_t)
{
   // some special behavior
}

int main( ) {

  Foo(1);
  Foo(true);
  Foo(nullptr);
   return 0;
}
```

[see the code here](https://godbolt.org/g/Hjgq8y)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(conditional_t<is_fundamental_v<T> || is_pointer_v<T>, const T, const T&> x)
{
    //do stuff
}
```